# Lost Printer Access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printing, printer

I have a canon printer connected via cable to my router.  My main computer also connected by wire to the router is able to access the printer via network.  Every telephone using the WIFI from that same router is able to access the printer.  I have another computer connected on the 2G version of the WIFI that cannot access the printer.  I can access the printer utility via HTTP both on the wired and the telephones connected to the WIFI - albeit the telephones are on the 5G version.  The thing is that I was able to at one time access the printer through the computer on the WIFI and it went away.

The network is local.  The printer is enabled to share.  Short of reinstalling Windows on the computer, I am stymied at this point.  I can't understand why I am able to access the printer via WIFI through the android phones but not on the computer running Windows through the WIFI.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you set the Printer up with DHCP access and the IP of the printer changed, causing the lost access. Set the Printer up with a Static IP address on the main network, restart the Printer (turn off, wait, turn on) and set it up again with the main computer. Keep it on Static so it does not get lost.